# How do I avoid calling ".clone()" on same String in match multiple times?

Tags: regex, optimization, rust, copy, clone

#### Background:

I have some code ([Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/)) that finds ([Regex](https://crates.io/crates/regex)) matches and assigns the found values to fields in a `struct` named `Article` (where all fields are of type `String`):

```rust
pub struct Article {
  // user facing data
  title: String,
  category: String,
  subcategory: String,
  genre: String,
  published: String,
  estimated_read_time: String,
  description: String,
  tags: String,
  keywords: String,
  image: String,
  artwork_credit: String,
  // meta data
  metas: String,
  // location
  path: String,
  slug: String,
  // file data
  content: String
}
```

A regular expression (`"//\- define (.*?): (.*?)\n"`) is used to extract comments from the article's template that define data for that article:

```rust
// iterate through HTML property pattern matches
for capture in re_define.captures_iter(&file_content as &str) {
  // remove the declaration from the the HTML output
  article_content = article_content.replace(&capture[0].to_string(), "");
  // get the property value
  let property_value: &String = &capture[2].to_string();
  // determine what field to assign the property to and assign it
  match capture[1].to_lowercase().as_str() {
    "title" => article.title = property_value.clone(),
    "category" => article.category = property_value.clone(),
    "subcategory" => article.subcategory = property_value.clone(),
    "genre" => article.genre = property_value.clone(),
    "published" => article.published = property_value.clone(),
    "estimated_read_time" => article.estimated_read_time = property_value.clone(),
    "description" => article.description = property_value.clone(),
    "tags" => article.tags = property_value.clone(),
    "keywords" => article.keywords = property_value.clone(),
    "image" => article.image = property_value.clone(),
    unknown_property @ _ => {
      println!("Ignoring unknown property: {}", &unknown_property);
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: `article` is an instance of `Article`.

#### Issue:

The code works but what I'm concerned about the following part:

```rust
"title" => article.title = property_value.clone(),
"category" => article.category = property_value.clone(),
"subcategory" => article.subcategory = property_value.clone(),
"genre" => article.genre = property_value.clone(),
"published" => article.published = property_value.clone(),
"estimated_read_time" => article.estimated_read_time = property_value.clone(),
"description" => article.description = property_value.clone(),
"tags" => article.tags = property_value.clone(),
"keywords" => article.keywords = property_value.clone(),
"image" => article.image = property_value.clone(),
```

It calls `.clone()` on the same `String` (`property_value`) for every match (10 matches per article template), for every article template (a couple dozen templates in total), and I don't think it's the most efficient way to do it.

**Note**: I'm not sure if `match` is cloning for non-matches.

#### What I tried:

I tried referencing the `property_value` `String`, but I got an error for each reference.

**Error from IDE (VS Code)**:

```rust
mismatched types
expected struct `std::string::String`, found `&&std::string::String`
expected due to the type of this binding
try using a conversion method: `(`, `).to_string()`
```

**Error from `cargo check`**:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/article.rs:84:38
   |
84 |           "image" => article.image = &property_value,
   |                      -------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found `&&std::string::String`
   |                      |
   |                      expected due to the type of this binding
   |
help: try using a conversion method
   |
84 |           "image" => article.image = (&property_value).to_string(),
   |                                      +               +++++++++++++
```

I did try using `.to_string()`, but I'm not sure if converting a `String` to the same type is the most efficient to do it either.

#### Question:

How do I avoid calling `.clone()` on `property_value` so many times?

Comment: `article_content.replace(&capture[0].to_string(), "")`? Does `replace()` require `&String` or `&str`?

Comment: Also, `&string as &str` is usually expressed as `&*string` or `string.as_str()`.

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Comment: What's the definition of `Article`? Can you change it? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "the same string". If the string is same, why do you need the regex?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thank you for pointing that out, seems I was converting the type for no reason. As for the `&string as &str` tip, I'm not sure, seems I used `.as_str()` in one place and `as &str` in another.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the question and provided more information.

Comment: and what would be the "property" for `unknown_property` case ?

Comment: The `clone()` happens only for the active arm. I would clone befroe the `match` because of readability concerns, but it shouldn't matter for perf.

Comment: @Stargateur The last one is the default match, to let me know if I defined a property for that doesn't have a valid name. The `println!` is for debugging purposes, letting me know it ignored an invalid name.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Your advice worked. I got rid of all the clone statements and used a move instead, can't believe I didn't think of that before! Thanks man, appreciate it!

Comment: `let property_value: &String = &capture[2].to_string();` → `let property_value = capture[2].to_string();` then remove all the `.clone()` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the types, you should just be able to drop the borrow in `property_value` and then you don't need the `.clone()`s.

```rust
let property_value: &String = &capture[2].to_string();
// change to
let property_value: String = capture[2].to_string();
// or just simply
let property_value = capture[2].to_string();
```

I'm assuming this was added as `capture[2]` returns a `str` (non-sized type) which would require the `&` but with `to_string()` it converts to the owned type `String` which is fine on it's own. This wont have any performance effect as `to_string()` copies anyway.